# Persist variable outside subscriber

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple function that return a converted date depending of offset received from query as:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'timezone' })
export class TimezonePipe implements PipeTransform {

convertedDate

    constructor(
        private configStateService: ConfigStateService,
        private identityUserService: IdentityUserService,
        private timeZoneService: TimeZoneService
    ) { }


    transform(value: string): string {
        const currentUserId = this.configStateService.getOne("currentUser").id;

        this.identityUserService.get(currentUserId).subscribe((user) => {
            const userTimeZoneId = user.extraProperties.TimeZoneId
            this.timeZoneService.getList().subscribe((timeZoneList) => {
              const offSet = timeZoneList.items.find(timeZone => timeZone.id === userTimeZoneId).utcOffset
              const date = new Date(Date.parse(value));
              date.setHours(date.getHours() + offSet);
              this.convertedDate = date.toLocaleString();
            })
        })
      return this.convertedDate
    }
```

The issue is when I'm assigning the variable inside the `subscribe`, it works:  `this.convertedDate = date.toLocaleString();` the variable got the value correctly

But it is always undefined when it returns; what do I need to do to the `this.convertedDate` value that persists outside the subscriber and returns it correctly?

I changed the code to:

```
transform(value: string): Observable<string> {
      const currentUserId = this.configStateService.getOne("currentUser").id;
        return this.identityUserService.get(currentUserId).pipe(
          switchMap(user => {
            const userTimeZoneId = user.extraProperties.TimeZoneId;

            return this.timeZoneService.getList().pipe(
              map(timeZoneList => {
                const offSet = timeZoneList.items.find(timeZone => timeZone.id === userTimeZoneId).utcOffset;
                const date = new Date(Date.parse(value));
                date.setHours(date.getHours() + offSet);
                return date.toLocaleString();
              })
            );
          })
        );
      }
```

HTML:

```
{{ row.sentDateTime | customTimeZone | async }}
```

And now, it is working, but I want to know if is a better way to do this because now, this is subscribing on each pipe call, and that can be a disaster on performance later

Comment: Where are you going to use the value of convertedDate?

Comment: Actually this is a custom pipe, I will use it in an HTML component as:      `{{ row.sentDateTime | timezone }}`, (full component added to the question), @nicolascolman

Comment: You are mixing async code with non-async code. Of course that `this.convertedDate` is undefined when you function is returning it because it is executed before the subscribe block of code(which is asynchronous). Having async code in pipe transform will not work (maybe with promises but it's still just a no-angular way). I recommend to move the async code in the component and wait until it is executed (basically just make an ngIf in HTML until you have the value in the component)

Comment: Pipes are ordinarily meant to be pure. Calling a service from a pipe conflicts with this and in any case is not common practice.

Comment: And what did you guys recommend if I want to change the dates depending of the received offset? I do not want to write the same code on all components to change the date offset; also can you give an example of *ngIf? I guess you're saying run a function on a HTML *ngIf, and that function calls the pipe? @TJ96

Comment: I think that your best option is to repeat a bit of code in your components

Comment: There is a guide page on this. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#caching-http-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid multiple subscriptions on pipe calls, you can use `shareReplay` operator with buffer size 1 which will return the latest value to subscribers without re-executing the pipe again.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'timezone' })
export class TimezonePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    private configStateService: ConfigStateService,
    private identityUserService: IdentityUserService,
    private timeZoneService: TimeZoneService
  ) { }


  transform(value: string): Observable<string> {
    const currentUserId = this.configStateService.getOne("currentUser").id;
    return this.identityUserService.get(currentUserId).pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        const userTimeZoneId = user.extraProperties.TimeZoneId;
        return this.timeZoneService.getList().pipe(
          map(timeZoneList => {
            const offset = this.getUtcOffeset(timeZoneList, userTimeZoneId)
            return this.getDate(value, offset);
          }),
          shareReplay(1)
        );
      })
    );
  }

  getUtcOffeset(timeZoneList: any, userTimeZoneId: any) {
    const offSet = timeZoneList.items.find(timeZone => timeZone.id === userTimeZoneId).utcOffset;
    return offSet;

  }

  getDate(time: string, offSet: number) {
    const date = new Date(Date.parse(time));
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + offSet);
    return date.toLocaleString();
  }
}
```

Comment: please set pure flag to false inside pipe decorator.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work in the 1st case is that you are mixing sync and async code. You return value synchronously, but at the time it wasn't assigned a value so it returns undefined which is expected. The value is assigned later, but the transform pipe is all about running a function and returning its value once.

In the second example it works because you are returning an Observable which is then subscribed to via `async` pipe and so is unwrapped.

To fix the issue with multiple requests per page you have two options:

1. Create a service which is provided on this page via `providers` and inject it in the pipe. Service should hold the request to the server in a prop. It should be piped through `shareReplay()` then new subscriptions would re-use the value from previous run. You could also use a Promise which is even simpler to operate with in given circumstances.
2. Do the data transformations inside your service which retrieves the data. And this one seems more optimal in my point of view as this is the entry point of the data and the request will be made just once. Then it can be reused synchronously with no overhead of playing around `providers` etc. If you need your date to be displayed in multiple formats - you can easily achieve it by adding properties with formatted date. All the data you hold - you do it as it's convenient for you to work with. It shouldn't necessarily reflect the data structures on the backend/DB.